# When does the Newton Raphson method fail?

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation, newton-raphson

Can someone please tell me the conditions under which the Newton Raphson method will not converge?

I looked around online, and couldn't find a general way to determine convergence.

For example, for the Fixed Point iteration method, there is a simple way of determining: if we have $g(x_{n})=x_{n+1}$, then $|g'(x)|<1$ implies that the series $g$ will converge to its fixed point, but in the Newton Raphson method, It seems like it is totally depends on "luck", meaning if you were lucky enough to pick a "good" initial guess or not.

Comment: The condition for the fixed iteration method to converge is far from *that*"simple. And if you look closely, Newton-Raphson *is* fixed-point iteration, just of a different function.

Comment: Some examples are given by lhf in answering [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89345/a-function-for-which-the-newton-raphson-method-slowly-converges?rq=1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the NR method can be written as follows:
$$
x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)},
$$
it means that it cannot converge as soon as:

- $x_n$ is a local minimum/maximum of $f(\cdot)$;

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, @7raiden7, thanks for the help.
Although these are good points, and helped a lot, this still will not help me figure out in advance which $x_0$'s will cause convergence. for example, according to your first point, I can find myself picking some $x_0$, and on sheer luck (or, more accurately, bad luck) "step on a mine" - meaning stepping on an $x_k$ which satisfies $f'(x_k)=0$. and that's exactly what I wand to avoid. (the second point can help me decide to avoid the NR method altogether).

Comment: Therefore you may want to check some modified NR method. I've never gone through that, but I guess that for you should pose a tolerance for $f'(x_n)$, like a flux limiter. Unfortunately this is a very tough field, it is very far from being simple. I recommend you to read some paper about fixed point theory/numerical root finding. You should also consider reducing the accuracy in favour of more stability, i.e. going for the bisection method or affine ones.

Comment: -1: because the last sentence in the answer is not true as stated. For instance take  $f(x)=x^2$, it has a root with multiplicity two at the origin, and the NR interation is $x_{n+1}=x_n/2$, which converges beautifully to the root, zero.

Comment: @MartinArgerami you're right, I've edited the answer, thanks for that!

Comment: or an inflection point.  doesn't need to be local min/max

Answer (score 11):

To visualize geometrically what's going on, I will code an interactive diagram with [GNU Dr. Geo](http://drgeo.eu) (free software of mine) from where I can drag the initial value (the red dot) and see how the method converge or not.

For example $x \rightarrow cos x + x$, comes with some mines, but not $x \rightarrow cos x +1.1x$.

When you get close to a *flat area*, the tangent sends you far away, even further than your initial value.

[image]

Your best option is to get close to the root in an area without nul value of the derivative. I guess it is the tough part as it depends on the function. Visualizing can help.

[image]

[This article explains](http://blog.drgeo.eu/post/2019/The-Newton-Raphson-Method) how to code with Pharo+DrGeo this interactive diagram and the link with the Hero method from the classical period.

Comment: +1: this gives rise to a new type of problem, i.e. find $x_0$ such that, say, $x_6 = x_0$. Having to actively hunt for examples that trigger a cycle will help students remember it far better than being presented with a standard case. Kind regards

Answer (score 2):

Think geometrically about how the method works. We draw a tangent line to a curve. We follow that tangent down (or up) to the $x$-axis. Then, we jump up to the function at that point and repeat.

Now, what happens if the tangent line overshoots the root and sends us to a point on the function where the tangent line has the opposite slope? Can you visualize the ping-pong behavior?

What happens if the slope is very small (i.e. a flat tangent line)? What happens if the slope is very steep (i.e. a nearly vertical tangent line)?

Comment: yes, I understand the geometry implication. that alone made me wonder about the unexpected behavior of an initial $x_0$.

Comment: In fact, some several trips around the sun ago, I recall this exact example being on my numerical analysis final exam.