# In Case of Oscillation Sequence of Newtonian Method

Tags: roots

I am learning the basic concept of Newtonian method and text book introduces a function which newtonian step values are Oscillating as a example which is Newtonian method is inapplicable. However, I think for any kind of differentiable function at all domain, oscialltion guarantees the where the root is since if $x_n$ oscialltes between 1+h and 1-h where h>0, root would be 1.

Isn't it true?

---

example added.

$f(X) = \sqrt{x-1}, x\ge1$ and $-\sqrt{x-1}, x\le1$

In this case we can verify that the newton method keep oscillating about $x =1$

However, I think, Osciallation is good thing since we can just guarantee that that oscillating criterion becomes root.

Isnt't it?

Comment: @Moo Added at OP. thx

Comment: Which book? Perhaps it means *cycles*, which can happen in Newton's method. See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/89350/589.

Comment: @Ihf this book written in Korean. How the ordinary books introduces the Cycles case?